# 403 Response from Power BI Rest API

Tags: java, azure, active-directory, azure-web-app-service, powerbi

I am getting a 403 response from the Power BI rest API and I am not sure why.

Here is the request I am making in cURL format(my actual web app is in Java):

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer accessToken" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" 'https://api.powerbi.com/beta/myorg/dashboards'
```

I have given all Power BI Service permissions on my app in the azure management portal.

Do I need to replace 'myorg' with an actual org name? If so where would I find my org name? What am I doing wrong? This request seems to work for me in Aipary.io so I think it has something to do with my app not the request.

I have tried this request with both an admin account and a regular user and I get 403 responses for both of them.

I have also tried removing the Power BI Service permissions from the app with my admin account and then adding them again. That didn't work.

Comment: Which permission scopes did you select when you registered your app?

Comment: I selected all of the delegated permission scopes for Power BI Service, Windows Azure Active Directory, and the resource app.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that the 403 response was caused by the request in `cURL` missing some required parameters. The 403 response should show the error information that might be ignore.

Per my experience, I recommand you can try to use the GUI tool `Postman` in Chrome for requesting the APIs like `cURL`.

For checking the issue, you can follow the toturial https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-authenticate-a-web-app/ to make sure the request required parameters correct.

However, according to your description for the issue, I can't locate the problem whether the prepare steps cause. So I suggest you can try to review the complete toturial https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-steps-to-create-a-power-bi-app/ to be sure the every step is correct.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: What were you passing in on the authorization header? Without a valid access token, you would get a 403.